# Problem of understanding with questions KNN (k-Nearest Neighbors)

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, python, k-nearest-neighbour

here is my question it writes that "use the KNN model to classify these objects but we have 2 class then is it not already classed?
and how can I make the prediction with k=1?

[image]

Comment: Basically ignore the class of each member and find out what a knn with k=1 would classify it if it didn't already have a class. Then evaluate how accurate knn with k=1 is using a [confusion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) (which is useful to determine [Sensitivity and Specificity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity))

Comment: What is the first step to find out what a knn with k=1? by calculating what? And for the confusion matrix, I don't know how to calculate TP, FP, FN and TN, can you explain me sir? You can see what I do below cf. the image attached.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do for the confusion matrix

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For each subject (row) ignore the true label. Instead, determine the nearest neighbor among the other four rows. Whichever row corresponds to the nearest neighbor, take that row’s label as the predicted label.

Doing that results in five predictions, one for each row. Since we have the true labels, we can compare the true and predicted labels in a [confusion-matrix](/questions/tagged/confusion-matrix) like we would for any set of predicted and true labels.